# What is the best way of describing day of week?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I planning my inaugural data load into GAE and really want to get my ducks in a row.  The language I am using is Python. My question is about the storing of storing read only temporal data in app engine.

I have a spreadsheet with ~50k rows times 30 columns.

It is historic data and the table will be read-only.

I envisage a lot of sorting by day of week (show me weekends in July and so on) and also time (not necessarily always with date - but sometimes with) so my initial thought would be to create an extra row and fill that in a previously-computed "day of week".

```
eg.
date, time, dayofweek, event, geolocation, etc
27-02-2009, 08:20:00, 'Friday' ...
```

That date and time shown above reflects how it is coming from the spreadsheet ATM.

If I am going to go to the trouble of computing the "dayofweek", which is I presume a good idea, and given your experience of GAE's Datastore models should I:

-just have a single datetime? (and let GAE work out the day of week during future sorts/requests?)
-create a dayofweek but have a single daydate? '2009-02-27 08:10:00'
-store day of week as an integer instead? (0 = Monday in Python IIRC)
-store date as '2009-02-27' instead?

Output will always be English, and may also be JSON.  It is for a data visulatisation study and some extra temporal animation could be done on the client - but my primary concern is to keep the work done in GAE down, which I admit might just be a n00bish fetish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to query based on day-of-week - that is, you need to select several Fridays, but not the neighbouring days - you should absolutely break this out into a separate property, as it'll make it possible to do efficient queries for it.

To do the query 'Fridays in July', as you suggest, you've got several options:

- Without a separate 'day of week' property, you could do four or five queries for each of the valid days
- With a separate 'day of week' property, you can do a single query on day-of-week and date range. This will use your inequality filter for the date range, so you couldn't also do an inequality filter on any other property in that query.
- With separate 'day of week' and 'month' properties, you could do the above query without using any inequality filters.

Answer (score 1):

You should just have a single datetime.  This will allow your system to be utilized by other systems as the need arises in the future. I also believe that computable items should not be stored in the DB as the parameters from some computations can evolve over time.

HTH,

Comment: Which day of the week it was at a given (past) time (with timezone defined) can't change, and he's not removing the datetime so this doesn't impact other uses of the data.

Comment: This is absolutely not the case for App Engine - like most nonrelational datastores, it relies on denormalization to make queries cheaper at the expense of higher work on insert/update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want maximum performance you can add dayofyear and year in your key name.
For example what I do is that i construct keys like that:
analytic:124:2011

Then it is quite easy to get the last 30 days let's. Just create a list generator that will create a list of keys for the 30 last days

```
from datetime import datetime
dof = datetime.now().timetuple()
keys = [db.Key.from_path("Analytic","%i:%i"%(dof-i,2011)) for in in xrange(0,30)]
analytics = db.get(keys)
```

Comment: I find this so intriguing. Is this a trick you can only pull off with GAE?  (still reading up on this)

Comment: You can do it for any key-value storage provided that you can control the name of the key

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you definitely want to break down your date in ways that make sense for queries. Building some of that information into the key *can* be useful as suggested as well. It is not always possible though. For example, there may be competing concerns for the key. 
Yet another option is to build a query index just based on date and use ancestor/parent relationship. Then you can do a keys only query on the date oriented entities and use them to get the parents.

One last thing, I recommend that, however you break down the date, *do* store the datetime in full as well. You may want his later if there has been some mistake or if you change your scheme.

Comment: Thanks Jay, yeah, I was planning retaining a full original timestamp just to leave the door open for further unplanned operations. Yes, the ancestor/parent relationship is something I will investigate much further now you suggest that I could be using it in this scenario.